# How to solve "ERROR: permission denied" to create database?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I tried to dump the database file inside my database table. But I got these errors. I don't know what this error means?

```
try@try-T3500:~$ sudo psql -U try rt3 < rt3-20191007-WengLi.db
Password for user try: 
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  permission denied to create role
ERROR:  unrecognized role option "nobypassrls"
LINE 1: ...HERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRL...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  permission denied to create role
ERROR:  unrecognized role option "bypassrls"
LINE 1: ...SER INHERIT CREATEROLE CREATEDB LOGIN REPLICATION BYPASSRLS;
                                                             ^
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
ERROR:  permission denied to create database
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "template1"
REVOKE
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "template1"
GRANT
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "mimos".
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout"
SET
SET
 set_config 
------------
```

Comment: First, you need to use a user with the appropriate permissions, and then you need to use SQL that this database understands. This is either a very old PostgreSQL version or some mutilated fork.

Comment: `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` was introduced in PG 9.6 -- seems like you are using a version prior to that